# Group oracle table by name and order by time desc with time should be maximum for today's timestamp

Tags: oracle, top-n

Suppose I have a table as below in Oracle database

```
ID      NAME        SAVED_ON
_____________________________
10     APPLE    10-DEC-17 03.08.26.353000000 PM
15     MANGO    10-DEC-17 05.08.26.353000000 PM
17     APPLE    10-DEC-17 04.08.26.353000000 PM
19     APPLE    10-DEC-17 02.08.26.353000000 PM
23     MANGO    10-DEC-17 01.08.26.353000000 PM
```

My Requirement is :
I need all the distinct id's but taking the above table as example,
For `Apple` we have `3` entries in the table and similarly for `mango` we have `2` entries but I need a sql query
which will give the `id` of the entry of the `apple` and `mango` which was saved at the last i.e `maximum saved_on timing`.

i.e group by name and order by saved_on and final result should be id's with `max(saved_on)`

The ouput should come as `Id`'s- `15,17`

Answer (score 0):

Use an inline view to rank each fruit in descending timestamp order, which provides the filter in the outer query.

```
select id, name, saved_on 
from (
    select id, name, saved_on 
           , row_number() over (partition by name order by saved_on desc) as rn
    from fruit
    where saved_on >= trunc(sysdate)
)
where rn = 1
order by name, id
/
```

> "the day needs to be filtered for today timestamp"

Assuming that `saved_on` is a doesn't contain future values, it's simple  enough: truncating `sysdate` gives the date with a time of midnight.

Comment: Hi, One more thing is the day needs to be filtered for today timestamp. Can you please help in appending this condition.

Comment: select id, name, saved_on 
from (
    select id, name, saved_on 
           , row_number() over (partition by name order by saved_on desc) as rn
    from fruit where saved_on =current_timestamp
)
where rn = 1
order by name, id. Can you please help me to filter the current list which I am getting with only those entries made on current timestamp. saved_on is stored as timestamp(6) in my table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE` in combination with `DISTINCT` :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT name,
        FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY saved_on DESC) id,
        FIRST_VALUE(saved_on) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY saved_on DESC) saved_on
   FROM fruit
  ORDER BY name
```

See [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions059.htm#SQLRF00642) for more informations

Comment: Hi, One more thing is the day needs to be filtered for today timestamp. Can you please help in appending this condition.

Comment: I tried as -  SELECT DISTINCT name,
        FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY saved_on DESC) id,
        FIRST_VALUE(saved_on) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY saved_on DESC) saved_on
   FROM fruit where saved_on >= trunc(current_timestamp)
  ORDER BY name but this is not working